# When using a Git reference repository do I need to do modifications in pipeline code

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-checkout

I have a big git repo and multibranch pipeline. I started to using a git reference repository in Jenkins. (Created a folder and applied `git clone --mirror git@github.com:my-user/my-repository.git`)

In the build logs it says "Using reference repository". But I didn't feel any speed improvement. Do I have to make modifications in my Jenkins pipeline code?

For example I have some commands in my pipeline as below:

```
checkout scm

stdout = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "git reset --hard");

stdout = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "git checkout master");

stdout = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "git fetch --tags origin");
```

Is that commands using reference repository or not?

Answer (score 1):

> Is that commands using reference repository or not?

No for [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) or [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset): those a local commands which a using the locally cloned repository, not the remote one.

Yes for `git fetch --tags origin`. to be sure, add a step with a `git remote -v`, to confirm `origin` is indeed `git@github.com:my-user/my-repository.git`

Answer (score 1):

Please see this ticket: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54612

It appears to be the case that when using Pipelines, the reference repository is ignored.  I'm seeing the same behaviour, and so it looks like the reason you're not seeing any speedup is because there isn't any speedup of any kind.

If you look at the Jenkins logs, you'll see that the executed git commands don't include a clone.  It does git init, followed by adding the remote and then fetching.  It doesn't clone with --reference, and it doesn't set up the info/alternates by hand.  In consequence, it's always going to do a full clone from the remote.

One potential workaround would be to add a second remote, specified before the real remote.  Instead of a URL, use the local path to the reference repo.  This works for me directly with the git command line.  It timed out when I tried it with Jenkins.  However, that may be an idiosyncrasy of the slave I'm testing with, and it might still be worth trying this out for yourself.  If this does work, make sure you use transient workspaces to keep the space utilisation under control, since it's copying rather than referencing, but it will still be much faster than downloading the entire repository.

Comment: The bug is for Windows only. While I cannot say anything about that environment, we have significant speedup on Linux when using the reference repo.

Comment: @MaratC The bug is not Windows only; the title is a misnomer, and you'll see people suffering from the issue on Ubuntu as well if you read the last comment on that ticket.  As I described above, the issue is with the sequence of operations the Git SCM plugin performs, which make no provision for using a reference repository, making the reference repository configuration option pointless.  This affects all platforms.

Comment: we started using the reference repo in our Jenkins setup, and it has brought up extremely significant speed improvements for the `git clone` stage. It wouldn't be working if "no provision for using a reference repository" was made.

Comment: Would you care to share the exact commands which Jenkins runs to achieve this?  Note that the bug appears specific to pipelines.  It's not using "git clone", which is why this is a problem in the first place.

Comment: My pipeline has `checkout scm`, that's the only one relevant. We erase the workspace on each run and clone with reference (this takes ~20sec). For us, this works better than having a persistent workspace. Please note that the original ticket description has "[reference] seems to work on all agents we have except for our Windows nodes" and "I can use an sh step to clone using the ref repo successfully", so reference repo surely works at least for some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In our experience:

1. Reference repo does work for `git clone`. This step has gone down from 30+ minutes to under a minute in our environment. This basically says "if I need to bring a large blob from git but it's already in the mirror, let's save us some time and bring it from the mirror".
2. The mirror needs to be updated somewhat frequently. We have a job that does it 3-4 times a day.
3. `git checkout` needs the data from both the mirror and the remote repo, since the mirror cannot be reliably counted upon to be updated. Latest changes are brought over from the remote.
4. Somewhat counter-intuitive, operations are faster when you don't use any shortcuts to make operations faster. Specifically, limiting `--depth` slows things down when using mirror.
5. If a repo was once cloned without the mirror, it won't be using the mirror ever. You may want to erase the repo and recreate it using the mirror.

Finally, you can check the speed improvements (if any) on Jenkins slave with the following command:

```
mkdir -p tmp && git clone git@github.com:my_org/my_repo.git tmp --reference  /path/to/reference/my_repo.git/
```